# Avoid double query on the same table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, aggregate

I have two queries which are doing basically the same thing, but have different grouping, the first query (query 1) is used to populate a chart, and the second to populate a table.

Query 1:

```
SELECT key_id
       ,sum(salary)
       ,sum(bonus)
       ,created_at
FROM table
WHERE emp_id = 1
GROUP BY key_id, created_at
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT key_id
       ,sum(salary)
       ,sum(bonus)
       ,count(*) OVER() AS full_count
FROM table
WHERE emp_id = 1
GROUP BY key_id
```

I have created a function that returns those two queries in a json format, `chart: [...], table: [...]`. The problem is that I need to query the same table twice, because of my grouping. Is there any way of dealing with this situations?

Comment: If the number of rows coming back is small enough, it's completely legitimate to do query 1 and then do a second roll up in code/memory instead of query 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new 9.5 version has added [`CUBE`, `GROUPING SETS` and `ROLLUP` extensions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) to `GROUP BY` which can be used for such queries. If you have to do this in previous versions, one way is using a CTE, with something like (note that it's not the same exact output as your query, since I didn't know the type of `created_at`. I guess it's a timestamp and didn't want to mix it with the integer count):

```
WITH grp AS
  ( SELECT key_id,
           sum(salary) AS salary,
           sum(bonus)  AS bonus,
           created_at,
           count(*)    AS full_count
    FROM table
    WHERE emp_id = 1
    GROUP BY key_id, created_at
  )
SELECT *
FROM grp

UNION ALL

SELECT key_id, 
       sum(salary),
       sum(bonus), 
       NULL,
       sum(full_count)   
FROM grp
GROUP BY key_id 

ORDER BY key_id, created_at NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: @AndriyM: I think so, too. It's the difference I tried to address with `count_distinct_created_at_per_key` vs. `count_rows_per_key` in my query.

Comment: @Erwin and AndriyM thanx, I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you want to present your data, you *could* do it in a single query, a single query-level, even:

```
SELECT key_id
     , created_at
     , sum(salary) AS sum_salary  -- numbers per (key_id, created_at)
     , sum(bonus)  AS sum_bonus
     , count(*)    AS count_rows
     , sum(sum(salary)) OVER w AS total_salary_per_key  -- totals per (key_id)
     , sum(sum(bonus))  OVER w AS total_bonus_per_key
     , count(*)         OVER w AS count_distinct_created_at_per_key
     , sum(count(*))    OVER w AS count_rows_per_key
FROM   tbl
WHERE  emp_id = 1
GROUP  BY key_id, created_at
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY key_id);
```

This lists totals per `key` (repeatedly) for every aggregated row per `(key_id, created_at)`.

Detailed explanation for the technique:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied in PHP/PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)

If you actually want to implement `ROLLUP` see [@ypercube's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127225/3684) or this related one:

- [Grouping() equivalent in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/grouping-equivalent-in-postgresql/94822#94822)

Answer (score 3):

Since each row's values are aggregated twice, you could also try duplicating each row in a manner that would allow you to perform both level's aggregations in one pass. The query below uses LATERAL for that purpose:

```
SELECT
  v.key_id,
  v.created_at,
  SUM(salary)   AS total_salary,
  SUM(bonus)    AS total_bonus,
  COUNT(*)      AS full_count
FROM
  table AS t,
  LATERAL
    (VALUES
      (t.key_id, t.created_at, t.salary, t.bonus),
      (t.key_id, NULL,         t.salary, t.bonus)
    ) AS v
GROUP BY
  v.key_id,
  v.created_at
ORDER BY
  v.key_id      ASC,
  v.created_at  ASC NULLS LAST
;
```

As you can see, one of the copies has NULL instead of `created_at` and the query groups by the copied `key_id` and `created_at` rather then the original ones. The effect of this is that one half of the row set effectively gets grouped by `key_id` alone, and so you get aggregated results for both levels in one go.

I have to admit, though, that I have no PostgreSQL instance to test this solution and thus no idea how it will perform compared to the other suggestions posted.